# scrollTop solo funciona en un punto específico

Tags: javascript

Básicamente, tengo varios botones que me llevan a distintas partes de la página. al usarlo de este modo:

```
var seeBelow = document.querySelector('#down');

seeBelow.addEventListener('click', () => 
{
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 900;
});
```

todo funciona bien y al pulsar el botón "down" me lleva a la parte de abajo, sin embargo al usarlo en otro:

```
var aboutMe = document.querySelector('#sobremi');
aboutMe.onclick = function()
{
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 900;
    
    console.log("se ha clicado");
}
```

me lleva a la parte superior de la pagina

(en el HTML, "down" es un button, y "aboutMe" un "a")

PD: Tampoco funciona cuando lo pongo con addEventListener, pasa lo mismo que con onclick (vuelve a la parte de arriba de la pagina y se imprime el console.log)

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código HTML, probablemente ahí está el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que `scrollTop` es una propiedad de consulta, esta te responde a ¿cuál es la altura de mi scroll en este momento?.

Lo que buscas hacer de modificar la posición del scroll mediante Javascript se logra mediante `window.scrollTo(X, Y)` donde **X** representa el scroll horizontal y **Y** el vertical  (si existen). En tu ejemplo solo necesitas reemplazar

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop = 900;
```

con

```
window.scrollTo(0, 900);
```

---

Otra opción que tal vez estés buscando sería la de hacer scroll hasta que un elemento se muestre en pantalla, esto lo logras usando primero una query como

```
document.querySelector('#parrafo-1').scrollIntoView();
```